# C Input Through Pipe or Argument

Tags: c

I am looking for a method to pull input into my program from either a Pipe from the terminal or by specifing a filename as an argument. Effectivly

```
1. foo | myprogram
OR
2. foo > bar; myprogram -w bar
```

The second operation is accoplished simply by reading the file. However I am drawing a blank on how to redirect the output from `foo` into `myprogram` with a pipe. In all the examples I have managed to find Pipes have been used almost exclusively for IPC from parent to child processes. Am I thinking of the proper Pipe or is this a different mechanism?

I also realize that when `foo | myprogram` is executed the programs are executed simulatniously. How is this handled if `foo` is read in continuously.

EDIT:

Forgot to include this:

```
int main(){
    char buff[255];
    int i = read(0, buff, 255);
    printf("Debug: %s\n", buff);
    return 0;
}
```

If for instance I execute `ls | myprogram` I tend to receive.

```
. ../ files
Debug:
```

instead of

```
Debug: . ../ files
```

Comment: You're going to want to use the `dup2` system call.

Comment: Read also http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/

Comment: Doing a `read` like that isn't going to guarantee a NUL-terminated string, which is required for your `printf` to work properly. Also, the `read` will block until it sees 255 characters - and there won't be any room in the array to put the NUL character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
FILE* input;
//...
if (argc == 1) {
    input = stdin;
} else {
    input = fopen(argv[2] /* or whatever */, "r");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> The second operation is accoplished simply by reading the file.
>   However I am drawing a blank on how to redirect the output from foo
>   into myprogram with a pipe.

When using a pipe redirection, the shell sets up the `stdout` of the process on the left to go to the `stdin` of the process on the right. Just read from `stdin` as you normally would and you're set.